# Are there any APIs to draw custom maps in Android like Google Maps?

Tags: android, dictionary

I would like to customize the maps like satellite view ,maps view. I would like to add my custom view to the Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to supply custom map tiles to Google Maps for Android. You can create your own map tiles for the Web-based Google Maps and display that via a `WebView` widget. Or, you can see if Open Street Map and OSMDroid can help you with custom map tiles for their mapping engine.