# Custom tile overlay on Android maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, tiles

I’m working with creation of an app for both iOS and Android. A part of it is to display a custom map of a specific area on top of google maps. Just like the Apple's TileMap sample from WWDC 2010, mentioned [in the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793290/android-custom-control-to-display-map-tiles). More specifik example for iPhone [in this guide](http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2010/12/23/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/). On this second link you can see exactly what I want. A specific example are the Wacken app for both Android and iPhone with this exact feature.

I got this up and running on iOS in no time. But I can’t find any examples or information about how to do this on Android. I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710971/is-there-any-apis-to-draw-custom-maps-in-android-like-google-maps) saying that it can't be done without a webview, is that still true? Can you help me find a good place to start?

The answer I recived on this thread makes it clear : this cant be done natively. I'll look into the webview solution - fell free to drop some links here if you got good guides just to keep the thread interesting for future reference.

Comment: check whether this link is useful, i don`t know how its work .http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fosmdroid-android

Comment: It's possibly an option, but if possible I'd like to use Googles maps. Not sure how the coverage of sweden are with such a library either - and my overlay is kinda tailored to fit on top of googles map.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can’t find any examples or information about how to do this on Android.

The Google Maps add-on for Android does not support custom tiles. You are welcome to attempt to roll your own system as a custom `Overlay`.

> I have found this old thread saying that it can't be done without a webview, is that still true?

Considering that the answer you linked to was written only two months ago, yes.

Comment: Im quite surprised such a thing cant be done on a modern smartphone OS like Android, but I accept your answer.

Comment: I am now quite certain that the Wacken app for Android does not use WebView with google maps, but do use something native. Can anyone with some Android experience take a look at their app and comment on it?